# Row total results in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select only the names that have more than 10 total cases but I am unsure how.

```
,TT2 AS
(
SELECT VENDOR_ID
,VEND_NAME
,VEND_ADRLN1
,VEND_ADRLN2
,VEND_CITY
,VEND_STATE
,VEND_ZIP
,COUNTY_NAME
,CONTRACT
,MEMBERS
FROM FINAL

UNION ALL

SELECT VENDOR_ID
,VEND_NAME
,NULL VEND_ADRLN1
,NULL VEND_ADRLN2
,NULL VEND_CITY
,NULL VEND_STATE
,NULL VEND_ZIP
,NULL COUNTY_NAME
,NULL CONTRACT
,SUM(MEMBERS) 
FROM FINAL
GROUP BY VENDOR_ID
,VEND_NAME
)


,SH4 AS
(
SELECT * FROM TT2 
)


SELECT * FROM SH4 ORDER BY 2,CASE WHEN VEND_ADRLN1 IS NULL THEN 'ZZ' ELSE VEND_NAME END,8
```

The code above returns the first picture. I'd like to keep the names that have more than 10 in the row total but when I add it to the criteria it only shows the lines with 10 or more, not all for that name. I want to return all the rows for the ones that have 10 or more like in the second picture.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have SQL Server 2012 or later, you should be able to use the SQL Server windowing function SUM() OVER to achieve what you want.

```
WITH TT2 AS
(
SELECT VENDOR_ID
,VEND_NAME
,VEND_ADRLN1
,VEND_ADRLN2
,VEND_CITY
,VEND_STATE
,VEND_ZIP
,COUNTY_NAME
,CONTRACT
,MEMBERS
-- TOTAL_MEMBERS column will calculate total members by Vendor_Id & name 
-- via SQL windowing function. This will be used to filter the result set later
,TOTAL_MEMBERS = SUM(MEMBERS) OVER (PARTITION BY VENDOR_ID, VEND_NAME)
FROM FINAL
)
SELECT * 
FROM TT2 
WHERE TOTAL_MEMBERS > 10
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try using the GROUP BY query first by itself.  Add a HAVING SUM() >= 10 to limit it to those you want.  (This can be done later if you like.)

Then in the second query, union the above "TT2" with FINAL joined to TT2.  There's one and only one TT2 record per vendor you want, so a INNER JOIN will work.  A WHERE with an EXISTS would also work.

You can add a new column to order on if you want to avoid using the case in the order by.